# Why do SQL Server and MS Access return different results for equivalent input?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm migrating an Access project in which there is a division operating with a date value, the problem is that the table where the value must be inserted is `Float` type.

Given that Access and SQL Server return different results while operating the division or conversion to float, I need to know what is the math operation to create a function in SQL Server to mimic the Access conversion to double.

For example, the following conversion in MS Access.

```
Select CDbl(#12/31/2016#);
```

Results in 42735.

While the equivalent in SQL Server

```
declare @ADate DateTime;
Set @ADate = '20161231'
select CONVERT(float, @ADate);
```

Results in 42733

The actual code I'm trying to migrate includes the following syntax:

```
Select (NumericField - DateField)/30 From ATable;
```

Is there a reason why someone could divide a date by 30?, as you might know, when MSAccess operates with adding/subtracting would add/subtract days to the date, so if there were a default for dividing I wouldn't have to operate with the underlying storage of the Access date.

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You should try to found out what is doing your current function first. And then try to replicate the result.

Comment: dividing a difference between 2 dates by 30 could give an approximation of the months elapsed

Comment: well, even if access is connected to SQL server, it will give the same results as a local query. if you actually dumping then you don't explain where or how the NumericaField value is being set. It is VERY likely that the NumericField value is set by some date value, and thus the difference should be the same. We need more info on how the NumbicField is being set - it is VERY unlikely that the value is some number, but is based on some date conversion also.